# Reference for Local class field theory via witt vectors

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, class-field-theory, local-fields

I would like to find some books or lecture notes on geometric local class field theory via Witt vectors. I can't find any good paper on this subject.All approaches in the books to local class field theory known to me are based on formal groups or cohomology.

I would be glad of any reference.

UPD If I am correct, this approach should be written in 'Y. Kawada and I. Satake, Class formations II, J. Fac. Sci. Univ. Tokyo Sect. IA Math. 7(1956), 353–389'. However I can't find this paper in the Internet. How can I get an access to this?

Comment: Have you seen Hazewinkel's notes ["Witt vectors I"?](http://arxiv.org/ftp/arxiv/papers/0804/0804.3888.pdf) There in particular on page 9 several sources are listed for what you are asking.

Answer (score 3):

The preprint https://www.maths.nottingham.ac.uk/personal/ibf/ksm3.pdf discusses how to get the pro-p part of local class field theory following Kawada-Satake.